# Selecting nodes depending on several conditions based on descendants

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

Given the XML file below, I try to count (and once it's working, select) the number of cards having type = 1 and status = 2 but I don't find the solution using XPath cause I never code with XSL and I've been using XPath a long type ago with Saxon and I guess I don't have enough knowledge on that ... (XSLT 3.0)

Thanks for your help

source.xml

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="process.xsl"?>
<root>
    <card>
        <Prop prop_name="number" val="0001" />
        <Prop prop_name="type" val="1" />
        <Prop prop_name="state" val="1" />
    </card>
    <card>
        <Prop prop_name="number" val="0002" />
        <Prop prop_name="type" val="1" />
        <Prop prop_name="status" val="1" />
    </card>
    <card>
        <Prop prop_name="number" val="0003" />
        <Prop prop_name="type" val="1" />
        <Prop prop_name="status" val="2" />
    </card>
    <card>
        <Prop prop_name="number" val="0004" />
        <Prop prop_name="type" val="1" />
        <Prop prop_name="status" val="2" />
    </card>
</root>
```

process.xsl

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="nb_active_cards" select="count(//card/[Prop[@prop_name='type' and @val='1'] and Prop[@prop_name='status' and @val='2']])"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nb_active_cards" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Remove the `/` character between `card` and its predicate.

Comment: As already pointed out, a predicate condition is attached to a step expression without a step separator `/` so you want `//card[Prop ...]`. In XPath 3 .1 the syntax you have used isn't an error anymore as square brackets `[]` also are used for array literals so your attempt with `//card/[Prop...]` constructs an array in the last step.

Comment: @Slkrasnodar Expected result is 2 but I get 4

Comment: @michael.hor257k that's it! Thank you